# Prevent a stateChange with angular ui router without using $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My user can leave a state but before I want to show a modal dialog "Do you want to save?"

ONLY if the user data is dirty that means changed.

What I do NOT want is to stick a  isDirty property in my EditController to the $rootScope go to the stateChangeStart event and check there for isDirty and then show/not the save dialog.

Prevent global variables says every javascript beginner book...

1.) What is then the pro way to prevent a state change without hacking the $rootscope?.

2.) Are there any helper libraries for ui-router which enhance the ui-router offering function hooks inside the controller to encapsulate the ui logic?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

(1) According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) under **State Change Events**

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
          event.preventDefault(); 
          // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
          // a 'transition prevented' error
 })
```

You could change $rootScope to $scope wherever appropriate and works.

Under **Attach Custom Data to State Objects**, you can pass on custom data.

(2) I'm not sure what you're asking but factories/services/providers would really help.

Comment: Funny that I did not thought of the common local $scope always seeing all samples using $rootScope, maybe a bad example... your suggestion (1) worked!

Comment: I also just realized that I have to differentiate between logic run in the $rootState "stateChangeStart" only when a certain 'ToState' is activated (because I do not want to ask in any $scope.on("stateChangeStart) for a certain "ToState" ) and logic run when any State starts to change which I bind now to the local $scope to deal with the isDirty correctly.

Comment: How do you resume the event? Say I wanna do operations xyz and then resume the event and go to the wished state.

Comment: I think $scope may not work if the scope is isolated. But that's all

Comment: @molerat In that function, you could add $state.go(toState, toParams);

Comment: @molerat - beware blindly adding a $state.go() in a function for $stateChangeStart. This will cause a stack overflow if not careful. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Doesn't `$state.go(toState, toParams);` initiate another state change inside this listener? @molerat, just add an `if`-statement and only prevent it if you want it prevented, otherwise let it pass through.

Answer (score 15):

Using $transitions.onStart (angular-ui-router 1.0.0-rc) you can return a boolean. If `false` the transition will be cancelled.

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function (trans) { 
    var answer = confirm("Want to leave this page?")
    if (!answer) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the documentation: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html#hookresult

Comment: It's working, but I'm getting error in console `TransitionRejection(type: 3, message: The transition has been aborted, detail: Hook aborted transition)`

Answer (score 2):

Though at the time of writing it is not a part of the stable release, the 1.0 release of the UI-router will use the return value of onEnter/onExit to prevent navigation.

See [GitHub issue 2219](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2219)

Comment: `$scope.pn("$stateChangeStart")` still works with 1.0-alpha/beta when referencing the included `stateEvents.js` file and requiring `ui.router.state.events` in your app's modules.