# Angular UI Router - prevent $state from reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.3 and Angular UI Router and want to check user auth before loading a page.

For some reason, if `$q.reject()` is returned, the page is reloaded anyway (I can see it reload, and see requests made in the `httpInterceptors`).

I don't want any reloading of the page to happen. If `$q.reject` is returned, it should simply change back to `home` state in the URL bar.

Yet, each time a rejection is returned, it starts loading the next page and then redirects. How can I prevent a page reload?

**Code**:

a) Resolve user profile and then test their access

```
.state('user.agent-admin', {
  url: '/agent-admin',
  templateUrl: 'views/users/agent-admin.tpl.html',
  controller: 'userAgentAdminCtrl',
  resolve: {
    ProfileLoaded : ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
      return $rootScope.loadProfile();
    }],
    access: ['Access', 'ProfileLoaded', function (Access, ProfileLoaded) {
      // could be true or $q.reject(); 
      return Access.hasORRoles(['admin']);
    }]
  }
});
```

b) load profile

```
 $rootScope.loadProfile = function () {
   if (Session) {
     return $q.when(Session);
   } else {
     return User.getProfile().then(function (res) {
       ... // set session to user then return
       return $q.when(Session);
     });
   }
 };
```

c) On `$q.reject()`, this shouldn't reload the page, on change URL state back to what it was and prevent the page from loading.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
   if (error === 400) {
     $state.go('user.home');
   }
 });
```

---

**Note**: I do have an abstract parent state which has a controller that has http calls, so this explains the requests made. But doesn't explain why the page needs to reload.

```
.state('user', {
  templateUrl: 'views/users/master-user.tpl.html',
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'userMaster'
})
```

---

Trying with `$stateChangeStart` also reloads the page:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   Access.hasORRoles(['admin']).then(function (res) {
  }, function (err) {
    if (toState.name == 'user.agent-admin') {
      $state.go('user.home');
    }
  });
 });
```

---

I've also tried:

a) Rejecting directly

```
.state('user.agent-admin', {
  url: '/agent-admin',
  templateUrl: 'views/users/agent-admin.tpl.html',
  controller: 'userAgentAdminCtrl',
  resolve: {
    test: function ($q) {
      return $q.reject(301);
    }
    ...

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
   if (error === 301) {
     $state.go('user.home');
   }
 });
```

b) Preventing default ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787380/prevent-a-statechange-with-angular-ui-router-without-using-rootscope))

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   $q.reject().then(function (res) {
  }, function (err) {
      event.preventDefault();
  });
 });
```

c) Using new [UI Router 1.0.0 Alpha $transitions.onBefore events](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onbefore):

```
  // resolve user profile before any transitions begin
  $transitions.onBefore({to: 'user.*', from: '*'}, function(trans, state) {
   var substate = trans.to();
   return $rootScope.loadProfile().then(function (prof) {
      if (substate.name == 'user.agent-admin') {
        return Access.hasORRoles(substate.data.roles);
      }
      return true;
    });
  });

  $transitions.onError({}, function(trans) {
    var error = trans && trans._error;
    if (error == 301) {
        $state.go('user.home');
    }
    ...
  });
```

None which prevent the state change & page reload.

Comment: you should be leveraging `$stateChangeStart` to do the logic, rather than trying to force the state to error out and then redirecting in the `$stateChangeError`.

Comment: @Claies would I be able to use the new `Angular UI Router 1.0.0 beta` to accomplish the same thing? Because I've tried with `$transitions.onBefore` and it still reloads the page. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271974/angular-ui-router-1-0-0-prevent-route-load-with-transitions-onbefore

Comment: I don't know much about this new ui-router version;  I'll have to spin up a test bed to get some samples running and examine the behavior.

Comment: @Claies Hi, see the last edit above. I've tried with `$stateChangeStart` and it still insists on reloading the page

Comment: So, assuming your edit returns a reject, you have to explicitly call the state you want to go to.  For example, `AccessORRoles(['admin']).then((res) => { //success handler}).then(null, (err) => { $state.go('error.stateName'); });`

Comment: @Jason yes im aware- this is already happening as `$stateChangeError` would be catching the rejection. I've also tried what you just suggested and it still reloads the page (See above). Could this be related to something else within Angular forcing a reload? A rejection on `$state` should automatically cancel state loading, so why does it still load that state and also reload the entire page?

Comment: @Claies any more options / suggestions?

Comment: I faced same issue. To resolve this, I added code on $stateChaneheStart event.

Comment: @Ved please explain further

Comment: You can  register global state chaneg listerner,$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart''), inside your index.js file.